# Problema com caracteres especial em medidor de senha

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seguinte, peguei um medidor de força de senha que até funciona. Só que ele tem um bug que eu não sei que diabo acontece que eu n consigo resolver de jeito nenhum. Pra validar, precisa digitar 8 caracteres, 1 letra maiúscula, 1 número e 1 caractere especial. Ele tem um tipo "check" que vai marcando se vc colocou todas essas informações. O problema é que por exemplo, se eu começar a senha com um caractere especial, ele não marca como aceito, ele só vai marcar como aceito se eu colocar no fim ou no meio da senha. Eu não sei o pq isso acontece.
O código está aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/danielswater/vw028uk9/2/

Quem puder me dar uma ajuda, agradeceria muito

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, no regex de caracteres especiais, existe um ponto (.), esperando "qualquer" caractere antes classe de caracteres especiais:

```
if ( a.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/) ) {
```

Para corrigir, basta remover esse ponto:

```
if ( a.match(/[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/) ) {
```

Com isso, ele passa a validar o caractere especial digitado em qualquer parte da senha.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Cara, vc só pode ser um anjo kkkkkkkkkkkkk. Muito obrigado cara, vc não tem idéia de quanto ajudou